# Unique unchanged identifier for gameobject in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have to store information about every object (gameobject/mesh) in an excel file. Like I have a sphere object I am getting its instanceId and saving it in excel. Within the excel file along with object instance id i am saving additional things like object display name, type.

```
  objInstanceId = transform.GetInstanceID();
```

My question is that is the safest way? I checked that `instanceID` is unique but I am not sure if it is gets changed ever? Like if I replace my model will it get changed? I need a unique and unchanged identifier for every single mesh so that I can save it in an excel file and associate some data with the identifier!

Comment: Id say you would need to make a component that generates its own guid and once it has one it keeps it

Comment: Yeah nice idea, but how do I persist it? Suppose if I bring back my model in the hierarchy! Then it will create newguid and my data save with old guide will no longer work.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan how about saving a unique ID for each instance of your component in a serialized field -> persistent .. could you extend your exact use case a little bit? Like are all these objects in the scene from the beginning? Do you add/remove them on runtime?

Comment: I don't add/remove it on runtime but on editor, we often replace models after the updates. Like if a FBX has updated in modeling tool then we replace it in the scene. So that all modeling changes reflect correctly in the scene.

Comment: Your question seems to contradict itself. If you want a unique Id for each mesh shouldn’t it change when you change the mesh? I think you want to store the guuid that is present in the mega files. As that is persistent. Take a look at the structure of the scene yml. To see how unit itself stores these references.

Answer (score 3):

Let's take a look at the docs:

> The instance ID of an object is always unique.
> The ID changes between player runtime and Editor sessions. As such, the ID is not reliable for performing actions between the Editor and runtime sessions, for example, loading an object state from a save file.

https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.GetInstanceID.html

So within a runtime session the id is guaranteed to be unique. Between sessions the ids may change.

In other words, exporting all instance ids, adding/changing values and then importing them again will work within a runtime session (when the app is running).

It won't work when you close the app and start another runtime session, in which case any created objects will have different ids.

Comment: Thanks but i am looking for the solution.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan then clarify what your end goal is and give more focus to your question.

Comment: my goal is to save data for each and every  object. The data will be its display name and type.  So there are two string which i want to save and both are change able.

Comment: But if you only change the FBX outside of Unity and then save it at the same file location and then go back into Unity then Unity anyway will keep the reference correctly and everywhere the new Mesh will be used where it was used before ..

Answer (score 0):

If you want a unique persistent ID I would use a serialized field and make it hidden like e.g.

```
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

// See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExecuteInEditMode.html
[ExecuteAlways]
public class UniqueID : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Serialize/saves the unique ID
    // but hide it in the Inspector -> we don't want to edit it manually
    // uint allows around 4 Million IDs that should be enough for most cases ;)
    [HideInInspector] private uint _id;
    private static List<uint> usedIds;

    // Public read-only accessor
    public uint ID => _id;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    // Due to ExecuteAllways this is called once the component is created
    private void Awake()
    {
        if (!Application.isPlaying && _id == 0)
        {
            _id = GetFreeID();
            usedIDs.Add(_id);

            EditorUtility.SetDirty(this);
        }
    }
#endif

    // For runtime e.g. when spawning prefabs
    // in that case Start is delayed so you can right after instantiating also assign a specific ID
    private void Start()
    {
        if (Application.isPlaying && _id == 0) _id = GetFreeID();
    }

    // Allows to set a specific ID e.g. when instantiating on runtime
    public void SetSpecificID(uint id)
    {
        if (Application.isPlaying) _id = id;
        else Debug.LogWarning("Only use in play mode!", this);
    }

    // Stores all already used IDs
    private readonly static HashSet<uint> usedIDs = new HashSet<uint>();

    private static readonly System.Random random = new System.Random();

    // Get a random uint
    private static uint RandomUInt()
    {
        uint thirtyBits = (uint)random.Next(1 << 30);
        uint twoBits = (uint)random.Next(1 << 2);
        return (thirtyBits << 2) | twoBits;
    }

    // This is called ONCE when the project is opened in the editor and ONCE when the app is started
    // See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/InitializeOnLoadMethodAttribute.html
    [InitializeOnLoadMethod]
    [RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod]
    private static void InitUsedIDs()
    {
        // Find all instances of this class in the scene
        var instances = FindObjectsOfType<UniqueID>(true);
        foreach (var instance in instances.Where(i => i._id != 0))
        {
            usedIds.Add(instance._id);
        }

        foreach (var instance in instances.Where(i => i._id == 0))
        {
            instance._id = GetFreeID();

#if UNITY_EDITOR
            // See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.SetDirty.html
            EditorUtility.SetDirty(instance);
#endif

            usedIDs.Add(instance._id);
        }
    }

    private static uint GetFreeID()
    {
        uint id = 0;

        do
        {
            id = RandomUInt();
        }
        while (id == 0 || usedIDs.Contains(id));

        return id;
    }
}
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear.*

*There might be some edge cases but I hope that gets you started.*

---

As an alternative you could probably also simply use two [`SerializedDictionary`](https://github.com/azixMcAze/Unity-SerializableDictionary) and directly reference forth and back between any type (like `GameObject` or `Mesh`) and a unique key (like e.g. the `uint`).

Comment: I have updated the script but yet to check how it will work if i re-attach the script.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan what do you mean by re-attach? Each instance of this script will have a unique ID .. this is not bundled to the GameObject it is attached to ;) you could of course add this using a `SerializedDictionary` and reference GameObjects and IDs directly as well ..

Comment: i have to attach this script to each object in order to assign the id? What will happen if i remove the script and attach it again to the object? Then the id will reaming same? or it generate new id?

Comment: Yes. And as said it will generate a new one except right after attaching it you call `SetSpecificID` with a specific ID ... it's just a start point .. for sure you will have to adopt it to your specific use case ;)

Comment: The id is getting changed each time i play.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to this, but here's the solution that I found that works very well for scriptable objects, although you could reference any file in your project and it will work.

```
ID = UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.AssetPathToGUID(UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(this));
```

Reference: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.AssetPathToGUID.html

This gets the ID that is contained in the .meta file. It **WON'T** change between sessions.